# How to know the probability of the number of failures units in a cluster with single unit failure probability

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

I have a situation at work, where we need to release a product. We found an issue that occurs randomly. After a thorough analysis, we were able to root cause of the issue. The fix for the issue is not controlled by our company but requires the whole world to change. The issue occurs on a node after 300+ tries, if we continue the reproduction process, I would say it roughly shows up 4 times for every 1000 unit tests on a single node.

The probability is 4/1000

The nodes are in a cluster, and the unit test that reproduces the issue during cluster operations. I want to know the probability of the issue occurring if there are 10 nodes in the cluster and the probability of the issue seen 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 times during the reproduction step on a 10-node cluster.

We also want to know the probability of seeing this issue for various cluster sizes.

Is using  the binomial distribution the right way to find the probabilities?

$$ p(x|n,p) = \left(\frac{n!}{(x!(n-x)!)}\right) \cdot {p^x} \cdot (1-p)^{n-x} $$

In a 10 cluster setup the probability of seeing a single failure is 4%

$$ p(1|10, 0.004)=\left(\frac{10!}{1!(10-1)!)}\right)\cdot{0.004^x}\cdot{(1-0.004)^{n-x}} $$

Is this is the right approach ?

This will help us get some data to check how many customers will see the issue? if this product is released.

Comment: Let's suppose there are $10$ nodes in a cluster. When a "unit test" is performed, is it performed on all $10$ nodes simultaneously? Suppose after a single unit test exactly two nodes have an issue. Do you want to count this event as $x=2,$ or do you say $x=1$ when *at least one* node among the ten have an issue after a single unit test?

Comment: We count it as x=2

Comment: If you administer $n$ distinct unit tests on a cluster of nodes with cluster size $c,$ then the number of nodes that report an issue is $\text{Binomial}(nc,p)$ where $p=0.004$

Comment: It is more like this: I have a single light bulb that fails to turn on. Repeating the experiment 1000 times, I see that the light bulb doesn't turn on four times. If I have ten light bulbs turned on/off at the same. How often will I have a single failure that is one light bulb not turning on out of 10 light bulbs?  Can I decide the probability based on my single light bulb experiment?